# Modal PartialView validation doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have very strange problem I have main form with datatable and edit details buttons in every row when i click on Edit button opens modal partialview and load data from table but when i click to save data validation doesnt work at all. When i click New button everything works fine and i dont know what goes wrong. I added

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

in my main view and

```
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

in partial and result is the same

Main View

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
            {
            dataTable = $('#userTable').DataTable({
                    "responsive": "true",
                    "ajax": {
                    "type" : "GET" ,
                    "url" : "@Url.Action("GetData","Customers")" ,
                    "datatype" : "json"
                    },
                    "columns":
                    [
                    { "data": "FirstName"},
                    {
                      "data": "Id", "render": function (data) {
                            return '<a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="Details(\'' + data + '\')" style="margin-right: 12px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" style=" margin-right: 2px;"></span>Details</a><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-success" onclick="Edit(\'' + data + '\')" style="margin-right: 12px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style=" margin-right: 2px;"></span>Edit</a>';
                      }
                    }
                    ],
                    "language": {
                        "processing": "<img src='https://gph.is/2gESFHh' />",
                        "emptytable": "Няма данни за изжедане. Може да натиснете бутона <b> Нов </b>"
                    },
                });
        });

        function Edit(Id) {
            //if (confirm("Наистина ли искате да промените този запис?")) {
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'Get' ,
                    url: '@Url.Action("AddOrEditPartial","Customers")/' + Id,
                    data: { Id: Id }
                }).done(function(result) {
                    $('#modbody').html(result);
                });
            //}
            }
    </script>


}

<h2>Users</h2>

<div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: white; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; border-radius: 3px;">
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom: 12px; margin-top:12px "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add New</a>
    <table id="userTable" class="display" style="width: 100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Name:
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" style="margin-top: 100px;">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Users</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="modbody">
                    @Html.Partial("AddOrEditPartial")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<table class="table" id="userTable">
</table>
```

PartialView

```
@model Sfuk1.Models.Customer

<div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel-default">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-body" id="panbody">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrEditPartial", "Customers", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/for-data", id = "formsubmit" }))
                    {
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSubmit" onclick="Validation()" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
<script>
    var Validation = function () {
        debugger
        var data = $("formsubmit").serialize;
        if (!$("formsubmit").valid()) {
            console.log(false);
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@section scripts` from partial view will not work in Main View, as the page is already rendered, you need to use @section scripts in main view.

Also, you need refer unobtrusive validation js file in Main view not in partial view "`<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>`"

Consider placing all JS code in Main View.

one more point instead of using HTML.BeginForm, try using Ajax.BeginForm

Sample Razor/HTML code ( Main View)

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Create";
  }

   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
     Create Blog
 </button>
<!-- Modal -->
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveBlog", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST",UpdateTargetId = "frmEmp"  }))
     {
 <div>
     <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                   <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create New Blog</h4>
                  </div>
                 <div class="modal-body" id="frmEmp">
                    @Html.Partial("_Blog")
                 </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
                   </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  }
```

Partial View;

```
@model BootstrapModalPopUp.Models.Blog

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@if (ViewBag.Message != null)
{
<span class="text-success">@ViewBag.Message</span>
}
  <span class="alert-danger">
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
  </span>
  <div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CategoryName, new { @class = "form-control" })
  </div>
```

Required JS files in Main View

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

Source: https://qawithexperts.com/article/asp.net/validate-pop-up-modal-using-ajaxbeginform-in-c-mvc/52
You can also check complete working sample or download it from above link.

Comment: @user12805845 ok great, upvote answer if it helped, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I installed unobtrusive-ajax and also added it in main scripts